# SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission from Lux renders parts of our app inoperable

Tags: android, android-support-library

For a few months, our application has been getting bad reviews due to a complaint from users that the main portion of our application cannot be interacted with.  Our app uses the support libraries and has an action bar.  According to these users, the action bar is the only part of the app that responds to user touch.  Everything below the action bar (except for the android home, back etc. buttons) is unresponsive.

After a lot of trouble on our end trying to reproduce the issue, we finally found that installing the app [Lux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vitocassisi.luxlite) causes this behavior.  When Lux is installed, the only thing that responds to user touch is the action bar.

Looking at Lux's permissions, I see this:

> **Other Application UI**
>   draw over other apps

Which, after looking it up, corresponds to this android permission:

```
android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

Users have already confirmed that the Lux application is what is causing the issue.

My question is, how can this be fixed without telling the users to uninstall Lux?  Is this an android bug, or ours? Is there something that we could be doing that renders our app unresponsive, but not others?

My next step I guess would be to send an email over to the Lux team to see if they know what could be causing this (alongside our own investigation).  My instinct is to also email the Android team, because in my opinion no outside application should be able to affect the behavior of another so dramatically.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what isn't happening?  Are you not getting touch events?

Comment: @GabeSechan, I just overrode the `onTouchEvent()` in our activity, and I can confirm that the breakpoint is being hit (we're getting touch events, but they're not propagating down to the children views).  I'm testing a custom view object for `onInterceptTouchEvent` now.

Comment: Did you ever determine what Lux was doing to cause this? I've tested a handful of apps and most of them work fine. The only breaking apps I found were Lux and GridWichterle (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.inmite.android.gridwichterle).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you by any chance using a view with the `android:filterTouchesWhenObscured` property?  When set to true, I believe this could be causing your issue.

For example, in the XML, it would look like:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
```

Remove the [filterTouchesWhenObscured](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3afilterTouchesWhenObscured) line and it should be fine.

Comment: THAT WAS IT.  Such a random and strange bug.  It looks like the OS registers the lux overlay as another view, and as a result filters touches out of the views that are embedded in our drawer layout (which is where that property was located).